# Splitting swagger json by tags

Tags: python, json, swagger

I have a single json swagger file complete with definitions :

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "tags": [
      {
        "name": "Tag1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tag2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tag3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tag4"
      }
    ],
  "paths": {
      "/api/v1/entities/{entityId}/status": {
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "Tag1",
            "Tag3"
          ],
          .
          .
          .
        }
        "get": {
          "tags": [
            "Tag1",
            "Tag3"
          ],
          .
          .
          .
        }
      },
      "/api/v1/entities": {
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "Tag2",
            "Tag3"
          ]
          .
          .
          .
        }
    }
}
```

On the basis of a list of tags, I want to create separate files

for Eg
list = ["Tag1", "Tag2"] --> 2 separate files : Tag1.json and Tag2.json are generated with their required references as shown below :

Tag1.json

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "tags": [
      {
        "name": "Tag3"
      }
    ],
  "paths": {
      "/api/v1/entities/{entityId}/status": {
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "Tag3"
          ],
          .
          .
          .
        }
        "get": {
          "tags": [
            "Tag3"
          ],
          .
          .
          .
        }
      }
}
```

Tag2.json

```
{
      "swagger": "2.0",
      "tags": [
          {
            "name": "Tag4"
          }
        ],
      "paths": {
          "/api/v1/entities": {
            "post": {
              "tags": [
                "Tag3"
              ]
              .
              .
              .
            }
        }
    }
```

In the corresponding generated files, unnecessary tags can be removed to prevent displaying empty sections.